# Siddhi Jar not appearing in carbon console

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing, siddhi

In WSO2 CEP, I have custom function which is doing some calculation; I have query like following

```
String cseEventStream = "define stream eventStream (attribute string,attributeValue object);";

String query = "from eventStream#window.timeBatch(10,0)\n" +
"select timestamp,custom:function(attribute,attributeValue) as data\n" +
       "insert into outputStream;";
```

Is it possible to show above input and output event stream in Carbon Console?

I have tried putting the jar file in respository/components/dropins folder but I am not able to see the streams in carbon console.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Siddhi Logger](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP420/SiddhiQL+Guide+3.1#SiddhiQLGuide3.1-Siddhilogger) to log/print the events. You can use it as shown below;

```
define stream eventStream (attribute string,attributeValue object);

from eventStream#window.timeBatch(10,0)#log("eventStream Event: ")
select timestamp, custom:function(attribute,attributeValue) as data 
insert into outputStream;

from outputStream#log("outputStream Event: ")
insert into tempStream;
```